# AWS Step Function - Is it possible to get the original input after using InputPath $.something?

Tags: aws-step-functions

My scenario is that I have 2 tasks in a parallel state. We use SNS and need the field "MessageAttributes" to reprocess the message through a DL queue.

The input I send to the step function is:

```
{
  "Body": { "Message": "This is the body" },
  "MessageAttribtutes": "These are the message attributes"
}
```

The tasks inside the parallel state have a "InputPath: $.Body" so the input to the tasks is

```
{
  "Message": "This is the body"
}
```

They also have a "ResultPath: null" so they return the original input.

But the output of the parallel state is

```
 {
    "Message": "This is the body"
 },
 {
    "Message": "This is the body"
 }
```

Is there anyway I can make the output of the state be like this?

```
 {
    "Body": { "Message": "This is the body" },
    "MessageAttribtutes": "These are the message attributes"
 },
 {
   "Body": { "Message": "This is the body" },
   "MessageAttribtutes": "These are the message attributes"
 }
```

This is my Step Function definition:

```
{
 "StartAt": "Process Videos",
  "States": {
    "Process Videos": {
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Next": "Finalizer",
      "InputPath": "$.Body",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "GPS Parser",
          "States": {
            "GPS Parser": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "x",
              "ResultPath": null,
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "Video Creator",
          "States": {
            "Video Creator": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "x",
              "ResultPath": null,
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Finalizer": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "x",
      "End": true
    },
    "ErrorHandler": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "x",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a misconception about the InputPath: $.Body.
I removed the InputPath from the Parallel state and put it into the 2 states inside the parallel state and it worked